# I tried to use document.write() only IE give the ouput

Tags: internet-explorer, document.write

I tried to use the following code to output the calculation using document.write, only IE give me the result. Other Browsers just give me back the form. And I cannot find out why?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function main()
{
    var area=form1.height.value*form1.base.value/2;
    this.document.write("<p>The area is "+area+"</p>");
    //return form1.area.value=area;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Triangle Area</h2>
<form method="get" name="form1" id="form1">
  <p>Height:
    <input name="height" type="text">
   </p>
  <p>Base: 
    <input name="base" type="text"> 
   </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Calculate" onclick="main()">
  </p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `document.write` like that. After the entire document tree is finished, `document.write`  will override the whole page. It can really only be used in inline pieces of script while the page is being rendered.

And even then, it's not recommended. Use jQuery, or for a really frustrating experience, `document.createElement(..)` and `appendChild(document.createTextNode(..))`